# Convert local coordinates to pixel values in python

Tags: python, coordinates, local, pixel, matplotlib-basemap

I have a dataset that contains local coordinates of tracking cars, and I have an image related to my dataset, I would like to plot my track on the image, but the coordinate systems are not matched. I also know the value of each pixel in the meter ( ortho pixel to the meter ), but I do not know how to convert my coordinates to the pixel value. Can anyone know how can I do it? if there are some sources or sample codes please introduce me, as I was searching and couldn't find anything. I am new in this area, so if someone explains from the scratch what should I do?

Thank you

I tried using imshow to open my image, but as I need to convert my coordinates to pixel values and don't know how to do it, I couldn't implement my figure completely.

Comment: How precise? Get metric and geographic coordinated of the corner of images. Then just do a proportion/interpolation with geographic coordinates. This works for "small regions" (less then several hundreds of kilometers). How to get geographic coordinates of the image? You should know it (as part of image metadata)

Comment: I want to project my coordinates exactly to the image, I know that the origin of local coordinates is on the corner of the image. Yes, I have lat location, Lon location, xUtm origin, and y UTM origin. should I convert them to metric? and then what should I do? sorry, it is a very new topic for me and it makes me confused. thank you for your time.

Comment: On both corners? UTM is already metric, but I think you should not care much about it. If you have lat_min, long_min, lat_max, long_max (assuming areas not too huge), and you have coordinate lat,long, you can calculate the relative position into the image (it is just a proportion calculation): y_pixel = y_pixel_size * (lat - lat_min) / (lat_max - lat_min) . You are new on the topic, but doesn't let confuse it. You have already all knowledge (you do not need topic concepts for such task).